# In the givenquestion, I am using theory of addition and multiplication. I am not sure if I am solving it correctly.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are $9$ new tennis balls in the box. Every game there will be
randomly chosen $3$ balls. After the game, these $3$ balls are used. These used
balls will put back in the box after every game. What is the probability
that after $3$ games there is at least $1$ new tennis ball in the box?

My solution:

$A$ - after $3$ games at least $1$ ball not used

$A_i$ - for game number $3$ new balls $i=1,2,3$

$A=A_1A_2A_3$

Comment: So what is the probability the first set of three balls are all new? Given that, the probability the second set of three balls are all new?  Given those, the probability the third set of three balls are all new?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Where do new balls come from? 'These balls are used'-what does it mean?

Comment: @Alex My interpretation was that you start off with $9$ new tennis balls. Once you have used a tennis ball in at least one game, that ball becomes 'used'.

Comment: @Henry (+1). Your way of thinking about this problem is exactly how I approached it.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a simple problem once you realise you can 'flip the question on its head'. So rather than considering the chance of having at least $1$ new tennis ball after $3$ games, let's instead consider the chance that *there are no new tennis balls after $3$ games*. This turns out to be a very simple calculation because there is only one way in which this can happen: no ball can be used twice. *If any ball is used twice, then there will be at least one new tennis ball after $3$ games*.

Now that we have thought carefully about the problem, the actual mathematics is very easy:

$$
P(\text{Never using the same ball twice}) = \frac{6}{9} \times \frac{5}{8} \times \frac{4}{7} \times \frac{3}{9} \times \frac{2}{8} \times \frac{1}{7} = \frac{5}{1764}
$$

Hence,

$$
P(\text{Using the same ball twice})=\frac{1759}{1764}
$$

as the probabilities have to add up  to $1$.

And, as we concluded earlier, if you use a single ball more than once, then there will be at least one new ball after $3$ games.